# How to create multiple table in Magento(extension) admin panel

Tags: php, menu, magento-1.7, magento

I create customize menu in admin panel(customized extension) in Magento. I want to know how to create block and Model for admin menu.

Here I just go through [this tutorial](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf) and create admin panel menu.

for example :

```
--News
   --Managed News
```

And also i create Different children menu in my customize menu.
for example:

```
--News
  --Managed News
  --News Details
  --News Management. and so on.
```

Here my code for create children menu in custom menu.

> app/code/community///etc/adminhtml.xml

```
 <menu>
         <news translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">
            <title>News</title>
            <sort_order>65</sort_order>
            <children>
                <manage translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">
                    <title>Manage News</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/news</action>
                    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                </manage>
                <weaves translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">
                    <title>News Details </title>
                    <action>adminhtml/details</action>
                    <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                </weaves>
            </children>
         </news>
    </menu>
```

And i create `adminhtml/NewsController.php` for first child menu and also create block(Include grid, edit,form and tabs) , model and sql (dynamic table).
But when i create same procedure `adminhtml/Detailscontroller.php` for second child menu.It willn't create dynamic table in my magento database.How to create dynamic table for custom module and also how to create
admin child menu's functionality (model, controller, sql and view). Guide me please.

Thanks in advance...